# How to set font size by \LoadClass

Tags: fontsize

I am using .cls file to make all style for my report. But I can not set font size for it.

In .cls file, I have:

```
\LoadClass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
```

When I set font size = 14pt, it make my font size smaller. T tried other value, such as: 16px, 18px. `\LoadClass` doesn't seem affect to the report.

How do I change font size? Thank for helping!

Comment: book only has three options relating to sizes 10pt 11pt and 12pt, they are not arbitrary lengths they are names of options, like draft or fleqn

Comment: So how to change font to 13px?

Comment: to select 13pt font at 15pt baseline you can use `\fontsize{13}{15}\selectfont` but a class option like `12pt` does far more than select one font size, it sets up all sizes from `\tiny` to `\HUGE` and spacing around lists and display maths and headings etc.

Comment: The `memoir` class, a superset of the `book` class has options for font sizes of 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, 20pt, 25pt, 30pt, 36pt, 48pt and 60pt. With some work on the user's part arbitrary font sizes can be used.